# Can't receive Motion Events with Window.Callback

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-window

My task is receiving all motion events in android application with good embedding (library variant). I create my Window.Callback wrapper.

```
public class WindowCallback implements Window.Callback {

private final Window.Callback wrapper;

    public WindowCallback(Window.Callback callback) {        
        this.wrapper = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
         return wrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(KeyEvent event) {
         return wrapper.dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {        
        return wrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    // other methods omitted
}
```

Then, instantiate it in `Activity`:

```
final Window window = getWindow();
final Window.Callback windowCallback = window.getCallback();
final WindowCallback callbackWrapper = new WindowCallback(windowCallback);
window.setCallback(interceptCallback);
```

But when I have `Toolbar` in `Activity`, this `Toolbar` capture `Window.Callback` in method `setActionBar(Toolbar)` or `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`. Code snippet from framework `Activity`:

```
if (toolbar != null) {
        final ToolbarActionBar tbab = new ToolbarActionBar(toolbar, getTitle(), this);
        mActionBar = tbab;
        mWindow.setCallback(tbab.getWrappedWindowCallback());
```

And `ToolbarActionBar` from support library:

```
ToolbarActionBar(Toolbar toolbar, CharSequence title, Callback windowCallback) {
    this.mDecorToolbar = new ToolbarWidgetWrapper(toolbar, false);
    this.mWindowCallback = new ToolbarActionBar.ToolbarCallbackWrapper(windowCallback);
    this.mDecorToolbar.setWindowCallback(this.mWindowCallback);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.mMenuClicker);
    this.mDecorToolbar.setWindowTitle(title);
}
```

Question is - How to check when `Toolbar` catch `Window.Callback`, but without creating base activity and extending from it. This check should execute not very frequently. (`OnGlobalLayoutListener` not our case)

Comment: what do you mean by captures? overrides? did you try first setting the toolbar and then setting the custom window callback to set it last?

Comment: Our realization use method `Window.getCallback`, but `Toolbar` from support library use original callback in initialization time. And our wrapped callback stop receive events. And we try set custom callback after `setActionBar(toolbar)` - it works. We want to create universal realization (library version) and don't worry about place of our library initialization.